# jQuery: grep() an array and get matching values out of it

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, grep

I have generated an array and now I am filtering it (with grep(), which I have never used before). Out of the matching results I need the FareIDs to display the divs that carry these IDs, but I don't know how to get to them.

```
function FilterFares() {

  $(".samplediv").hide();

  var matchingFares = $.grep(Fares, function(e) {
    return e.Segment == Segment && e.DepartureTime >= DepartureTime_Min && e.DepartureTime <= DepartureTime_Max;
  });

  console.log(matchingFares);          // OK
  console.log(matchingFares.FareID);   // HOW CAN I GET TO THIS VALUE ?? 

}
```

AND... how can I filter the same line for another Segment (in my example the Segment is 0 or 1, but there can be many more). How do I extend the grep function for that?

THANKS!

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/ukdmvy5e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matchingFares` is an array, so you need to access `FareID` like `matchingFares[0].FareID.`

This gets you every `FareID`:

```
fareIds = [];
for (fare of matchingFares) {
  fareIds.push(fare.FareID);
}
console.log(fareIds);
```